# Call a WCF service function using jquery when both the WCF service and jquery function is in different projects but in the same solution

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, wcf

I want to access the WCF function in separate project using jquery function in separate project.

CODE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "http://localhost:3241/EntityService.svc/GetGenders",
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            alert("success..");
            alert(result);
        },
        error: function (a, b, c) { alert(c); },
        failure: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
        }
    });


</script>
```

Web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAuthService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IEntityService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Ijson" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:3241/AuthService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IAuthService" contract="QHRAuthService.IAuthService"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_IAuthService" />
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:3241/EntityService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IEntityService" contract="QHREntityService.IEntityService"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_IEntityService" />
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:2214/json.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Ijson" contract="ServiceReference1.Ijson"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_Ijson" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

WCF service:

```
[OperationContract]
gender_obj[] GetGenders();
```

I always get Undefined error.

And using Fiddler i found that the error number is 400

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't know that this is your only problem, but it appears your script is expecting JSON data.  Your services appear to be using the basicHttpBinding, which doesn't support JSON.  For JSON you'd need to use the webHttpBinding.  Also, have you tried calling your service via the WcfTestClient to verify they are in fact working?

Comment: @chris.house.00 I have verified with WcfTestClient, the services are okay. Need to check by changing the Bindings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

different port may be like different domains (i don't know) so maybe you must use jsonp instead of json.

Comment: JsonP is ok. but you have to use it as GET request only plus seems to be having less security